# Operand should contain 1 column(s) sql when using case

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT o.rfq_id, s.name, m.manufacturers_name, o.ship_address, o.serial, o.model, d.part_type,        d.description, d.part_number, d.subs, d.qty, o.notes, d.action, d.vendor, d.pt, d.price2, d.buy, d.notes1, o.tracking_number, o.date_shipped, o.expected_date, o.po_no, o.issue_no, o.date_added, 
       CONCAT_WS(' ', c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname) AS customer_name,
       c.customers_email_address,
       CASE
           WHEN o.ship_address = 0 THEN (a.entry_street_address,
                                         a.entry_state)
           WHEN o.ship_address = 1 THEN (p.street_address,
                                         p.state)
       END AS Address
FROM rfq_order o
JOIN rfq_order_detail d ON o.rfq_id = d.rfq_id
JOIN customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customers_id
JOIN address_book a ON c.customers_id = a.customers_id
JOIN manufacturers e ON o.manufacturer = e.manufacturers_id
JOIN manufacturers m ON o.manufacturer = m.manufacturers_id
JOIN rfq_order_status s ON o.status = s.id
LEFT JOIN shipping_address p ON o.rfq_id = p.rfq_id
```

When I try to run this query it shows me error as "Operand should contain 1 column(s)".Please help me.When I use  CASE WHEN o.ship_address = 0 THEN (a.entry_street_address) then query brings me street address but I also want the state in address.Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `concat` both columns, or use 2 `CASE` statements.

```
SELECT  ...
       CASE
           WHEN o.ship_address = 0 THEN concat(a.entry_street_address,
                                         a.entry_state)
           WHEN o.ship_address = 1 THEN concat(p.street_address,
                                         p.state)
       END AS Address
```

Or

```
SELECT  ...
       CASE
           WHEN o.ship_address = 0 THEN a.entry_street_address
           WHEN o.ship_address = 1 THEN p.street_address
       END AS StreetAddress,
       CASE
           WHEN o.ship_address = 0 THEN a.entry_state
           WHEN o.ship_address = 1 THEN p.state
       END AS State,
```

Comment: Thanx a lot.I was wrong when I was using two cases.Its working now

Comment: if I am using your or part bcoj I want street seperate from state it gives me error.First one is working

Comment: the second one with two cases works when you put (a.entry_street_address) for each operand otherwise it will give you SQL error

Answer (score 0):

Your CASE STATEMENT is misconstructed. Use it like this:

```
CASE WHEN cond THEN exp1 ELSE exp2 END
```

Or:

```
 CASE WHEN cond THEN exp1
     WHEN cond2 THEN exp2
     ELSE exp3 END
```

You also can't put multiple columns there, it's one column. If you really need more columns, you have to concatenate them, or duplicate the case statement.

Comment: CASE WHEN o.ship_address = 0 THEN a.entry_street_address ELSE p.street_address WHEN o.ship_address = 0 THEN a.entry_state ELSE p.state END AS Address should I go like this?